# SQL Server "not exists" on unique key attempts to insert rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this example, `table_a` has a unique key constraint on `visit_id`.

Why doesn't `and not exists select *...` prevent SQL Server from attempting to insert rows from `table_b` with `row_id`'s that already exist in `table_a`?

```
insert table_a
    (visit_id, value1, value2)
        select visit_id, value1, value2, is_new
        from table_b src
        where is_new = 1
            and not exists
                (select *
                from table_a
                where visit_id = src.visit_id)
```

I am getting the error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line ...
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.table_a' with unique index 'IDX_table_a'.

The context here is an ETL routine that inserts new visits only, and updates existing visits in place. I know I can write it differently, but I don't understand why this statement isn't evaluated such that it wouldn't attempt to insert rows with existing visit_id's.

Comment: Maybe you just have duplicates on table_b

Comment: What columns are in the unique `IDX_table_a` index?

Comment: Very good point, if there's duplicates in b which doesn't exist in a this error could occur.

Comment: Yes! There's a duplicate in table_b, I feel like a idiot for not considering that. Thanks for your answers! Joe: the columns in both tables are actually identical.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that `table_b` has multiple rows with any given `visit_id` value? In other words, the violation may not be happening because a row in table_b is already in table_a, but rather because you are trying to insert two new duplicates.

You can check by asking:

```
SELECT visit_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.table_b
  GROUP BY visit_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Then, how you deal with it is up to you - you need to decide how to determine which row to keep.